# Postman does not send data to server and returns null response body

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am new in programming. I have web servre and remote mongo db server running. When i send post  i get the follwoing message, with request body as null.

To see the code, please refer to this:
[Postman socket hang up could not connect to Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662590/postman-socket-hang-up-could-not-connect-to-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment112609462_63662590)

[image]

Comment: how are you making that request? what should the request body be

Comment: {
    "name":"sal",
    "email":"sal@yahoo.com",
    "password":"1234567"
}

Comment: do you like to see the code? please see this post, this is my code   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662590/postman-socket-hang-up-could-not-connect-to-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment112609462_63662590

Comment: in that picture you haven't expanded the request body - what makes you think it's empty? is the request body empty on the client or on the server? perhaps your server code is wrong

Comment: I see on the server side you have `const bodyParser=require('body-parser');` ... BUT YOU NEVER USE bodyParser - so, how do you expect the body to parsed on the server if you don't parse the body on the server?

Comment: i am using app.use(express.json()); this instead. either way it still doesnt work

Comment: Oh yeah ... wonder why you bother with body-parser then ... so ... is the body null on the client (postman) or on the server (your nodejs thing)

Comment: when i post on postman it gives nulll. also can you please see if my mongodb connections string is ok: 'mongodb+srv://sal_abb:sal123@cluster0.ab0fj.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
}

Comment: so, the postman client is sending "null"? or is the body empty (doesn't look empty in your picture) - if the client isn't sending any body, then your mongo connection is irrelevant

Comment: Like you rightly observed it is not empty,

Comment: so, the client (postman) is sending the body ... therefore the problem is at the server side - which you have shown nothing for in this question - perhaps try using `app.use(bodyParser.json())` on the server - maybe `app.use(express.json())` is the problem

Comment: ok thanks, i will work on it,  more.I tried anothr code  it works. I think youare right it has to do with json. I appreciate your help and will get back on it tomorrow, getting late in here :)